# Is stack skeptics fair?

Tags: discussion

Let's say someone with high reputation wants to delete my comments or hide things from people. Would that be fair?
Since we disagree on any subject, it does not mean my words are incorrect.
Since having a high reputation, doesn't mean people know about everything.

Comment: Hi Alan. Most of the things you wrote are not actually answers to the question asked. I pointed this out to you. Please go and have a look at [The Tour](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour) which will explain how this site works.

Comment: If you want to prevent deletion, you should familiarize yourself with the rules of the site and include references within your answers. For example, if you had perused the Help Center, you would know that this question belongs on Meta, as the others pointed out.

Comment: Why the [tag:criminology] tag?

Comment: Alan, the only thing of yours that was deleted contained a huge logical mistake as well as not being an answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: Comments are temporary. They are all deleted eventually. Answers have a set of strict criteria. Without meeting those criteria, they may be deleted. This is universally true across the SE network, not just the Skeptics site.

Comment: Ok, no problem with you guys. I mean, I don't think is fair to delete my comments, Since the 'high reputation status', does not mean, the person can understand about everything. So, my comment must have some sort of value, it shouldn't be deleted. I guess. It should be free for people to value. Not the all mighty.

Comment: @AlanLanzoni: I am more active on SO.se that skeptics.se, but the rep system work the same. High rep users have amassed enought points to have the privilege to unilaterally delete post because such a high rep mean that even if they do not know everything, they are trusted to differenciate answer within the criteria of SE, but are wrong, which should be kept, and bad answer, that may even be right, that should be deleted. Everything a high rep user do, others with less rep can do if enought reach a consensus.

Comment: @AlanLanzoni Here we don't trust every user to be correct. Instead we expect them to explain themselves. As Sklivvz said, your posts are not deleted because they are incorrect, but because they are unsustainable (without an explanation there is no way to validate their correctness).

Comment: Isn't my following answer sustainable?

"If there are people entering the United States, then, there are terrorists entering the United States, since terrotists, are people."

For me, my answer was purely logical, therefore, sustainable. What do you think?

Comment: It's actually a logical fallacy described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politician%27s_syllogism). 

Your statement was:
*1. Some people entering the US.
2. Some people are terrorists.
3. Therefore terrorists are entering the US.*


This is wrong. The following statement would be logically correct:
*1. Some People are entering the US.
2. **All** people are terrorists.
3. Therefore, terrorists are entering the US.*

Comment: @AlanLanzoni Try this very similar sentence: "If there are people who are Republican politicians, then there are terrorists who are Republican politicans, since terrorists are people."

Comment: Ok. I understand. I'd rather use a logical system. Cheers... Oh ok, I get it. It can't be an answer because you can't take a conclusion.....

Answer (score 8):

Fair or not, that's how Stack Exchange sites are meant to work.

In particular this site requires people to look at the evidence in order to answer the questions. Your answer seem not to do so, therefore people voted accordingly.

It might seem harsh, but please don't consider it a vote on whether your answers are *correct*. It's a vote on whether they are *sustainable*, and it allows for the high quality you generally see on this site.